# My idea on parallel universes

Tags: spacetime, universe, spacetime-dimensions

I have a question I've long wanted to ask somebody and I see no place better than here to do it!

I am not a physicist in any way, Im just a big fan :)

So, I have an idea of parallel universes in my mind and like to explain it to myself in this way: (But I'd like to hear an opinion on it, to see if I'm even partially on the right track.)

Let's look at SuperMario for example: He is living a 2 dimensional life (and seems quite happy about it). He can go either left, right, up or down and that's it.

Now, if we say that the LCD screen is "SuperMario's universe" and we have an infinite number of extremely thin LCD screens stacked next to one another; No matter how close they are to each other though- two SuperMarios from different universes [screens] will never be able to see the other as they simply do not have the sense of a 3rd dimension, hence, being un-able to ever notice it.

So is this the same for us? Are we simply not built to notice a higher dimension- a 5th for example- when it could be right there in front of our noses?

Comment: Surely we are 4 dimensional- having length, width, depth and are living? I'm not sure if the last things actually what the fourth dimension is described as but still. :)

Comment: Ok. ok...we can say that time is 4th dimension as well. Im aware of that..

Let's say we are aware of n dimensions, there is n+1 dimension we are not aware of, and that's what I was aiming for :)

Comment: I'm cool with that. B)

Comment: if i may add, this would be a perfectly parallel universe (in the sense that they never meet anywhere) and in this sense it can also be superfluus, meaning even if it is like this or not, there is no difference, check http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486234002

Comment: Thans a bunch !
I was looking for something like this

Comment: You might also be interested to read about [brane cosmology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brane_cosmology). Note that this idea is highly speculative with no experimental support for it.